# Did Unity lose transparency in 14.10?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, design

I just upgraded to 14.10, and I noticed straight away that some parts of Unity which used to be transparent and show my blurred wallpaper, are now opaque - most notably the Dash:

[image]

But also the Application switcher, for example.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

See my filed bug and fix here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1385143/comments/2

Answer (score 0):

You could use the unity tweak tool to manually edit that setting. Maybe something went wrong while upgrading.

Comment: Where can I edit that setting? Also, does it not look like that for you? You also upgraded?

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool. I don't know if they have a working package for 14.10 yet, though.

Comment: I have that program. I'm asking you where in the program can that setting be found.

Comment: Search -> General -> Background blur on. Maybe play around with the blur types.

Comment: Well it is turned on and set to dynamic there...

Comment: I just upgraded, mine looks fine. I have to admit: I have no idea what happened during your upgrade process to break transparency.